# Proceed with wiring replacement ceiling light in bathroom after finding how it's rigged?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, bathroom, switch

New to switching out light fittings as of Wednesday; fitted a couple since then, isolating the supply at the consumer unit and double-checking the wires are no longer live using a contactless voltage checker.

Came to change the ceiling rose bulb fitting in our en-suite – which is already a warning sign as clearly not code compliant?! – and found the wiring a bit odd.

[image: updated image]

There are two grey cable feeds. I assume this is due to the fitting being on a loop, but I realise that the extractor fan in the bathroom is driven off the same light switch, so perhaps that's one of them?

Both earths connect to an earth terminal on the light fitting.

The neutral connects to the neutral for the bulb fitting (which is a brown wire, thanks to whatever genius rigged this). There is only one neutral and at time of writing I haven't made a note of which cable it emerges from...

Both live fittings connect to 'flex live' on the rose, stuffed into one terminal. The live for the lightbulb fitting is screwed into the other terminal.

My new light fitting has an enclosed plastic box within which there are screw terminals for live, earth and neutral.

Should I replicate the ceiling rose's existing wiring into the new fitting? E.g fit both live to live terminal, both earth to earth terminal, and single neutral to neutral terminal? Or is this existing setup as sketchy as it looks?

Diagram (sorry...):
[image: wiring to ceiling rose]

Comment: Can you post a better (i.e. not blurry) photo?

Comment: Can do (tomorrow!) - would a diagram be more helpful, as it's a bit of a mess?

Comment: if you can provide a complete diagram of the inside of that box, that'd work as well

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel updated image and diagram on the question: realising maybe this isn't as odd as first expected, as ceiling fan activated from same switch must be why there's a second cable with unused neutral? Question remains whether putting two live and two earth into the terminal box for new fitting is an OK idea. Will add an image of said box just now.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to leave a third link on the post - box for new fitting: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDDJE.jpg

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding the diagram, but if there's only one phase wire going over to the fan, and the fan's neutral wire is unused, wouldn't that mean that the fan must be putting current onto its ground wire to run? That seems bad...  Unless the fan has a second phase wire and actually runs on 220V... Personally I'd probably put in a proper ceiling box and make sure the fan gets connected in parallel with the light like it's supposed to be with no funny stuff...